# Why does diamond-graphite phase digram not contain a critical point?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, phase-diagram, diamond

I was curious as to why in all the diagrams I have seen that the diamond-graphite phase diagram does not display a critical point, do all substances eventually reach a critical point?

Answer (score 6):

I am unsure as to why you think there should be a critical point. Having a critical point means the phase boundary between the phases abrubtly ends and implies it is thermodynamically possible to go from one phase to the other smoothly without passing through a phase transition.

The most common and well-known critical point is the one from liquid to gas. There are no symmetry differences between the liquid and gas phases, unlike the solid phase where translation and rotation symmetriesare broken. Therefore you can go from the liquid to the gas phase smoothly by tuning pressure and temperature strategically.

Graphite and diamond on the other hand have different symmetries, so there is no way to smoothly from one to the other without a phase transition (diamond is cubic, graphite is hexagonal). The same is generically true for all solid-to-solid transitions which differ in crystal symmetry.